# Asp.net add class property as column to one table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mapping

I want to save properties of a 3D object in a database.
It happens, that i created separate classes for the position of the object in 3D Space, like this:

```
public partial class Object3DVersion
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("object_3d_version_id")]
    [JsonProperty("object_3d_version_id")]
    public string Object3DVersionId{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gps_coordinates")]
    [Column("gps_coordinates")]
    public GPSStringCoordinates GpsReferenceCoordinates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unity_coordinates_local")]
    [Column("unity_coordinates_local")]
    public UnityCoordinates_Local UnityCoordinates_local { get; set; }
}
```

So, .Net of course tries to put separate classes in separate tables and now complains, that there is no primary key in this class. But I don't want a separate table for coordinates, because these coordinates (x,y,z) are genuine to this 3D Object and don't need a separate table. Is there a way, to tell .net, not to create a table for this class and define a mapping scheme for this class instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063181/ef-core-database-specific-columns-to-nested-object